# Unscrollable list in a scrollable ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, telerik

I have something like

```
<ScrollView>
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
 <TextBox>
 <TextBox>
 *** // Tons of TextBoxes
 <TextBox>
 <RadJumpList> // Just a ListBox from Telerik
</ScrollView>
```

For now, the whole page is scrollable (due to ScrollViewer) and RadJumpList is also scrollable itself (by definition). How to disable RadJumpList from scrolling?

PS: probably, too many "scroll"s per a question, but i guess its pretty intuitive :)

EDIT: from my experience, this is bad idea. If list has 100+ items, it can delay page loading for a several seconds list would be loaded whole at once. Better idea is to put all TextBoxes to the ListBox via dataTemplateSelector.

Comment: If you set the VerticalAlignementProperty to stretch?

Comment: Remove Height Property from <RadJumpList> if any.

Comment: @Jaihind already removed, didnt help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set the height of your RadJumpList and disable scrolling like ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled".It will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even better way is to push all stuff into the list via ItemTemplateSelector.
Otherwise, if there would be 100+ items, page would load for a several seconds.